# Spring batch: chaining reader.processor, reader for the same initial data?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am  new to spring batch and researching the technology for some background processing  project. I have gone through the  doc   but  not sure it answers my question. So  I need to  chain  the following for the same  "stream" of data. read in , validate/process, and reread for new data(basically piping the same data though multiple readers sandwiched by a processor  . I am not sure if I am expressing myself  but  may be it is clear.
I know I can do  multiple reads but not sure  if injecting  the processor is  viable
Any  ideas, opinions,etc Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to do multiple reads you should consider chaining item processors after a single read before the final write.

The reason for this suggestion is chaining item processors allows you to take input, act upon it, transform it, and pass it along to the next processor in the chain.

Take a look at the section [6.3.1. Chaining ItemProcessors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors) in the Spring Batch documentation for more information and some simple examples.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Batch terms the "piping the same data though multiple readers sandwiched by a processor" sounds like you need a job with several steps chained one after another.

If in turn you want to feed the items (messages) obtained on one step to the next reader/processor/writer for further processing then you might be building a Message Driven Application and the Spring Integration might be a more natural choice to achieve the goal.